# Generate 24 combinations of 4numbers Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm going to create a permutation system but no idea at the coding in VB.net. What I want to create is, let's say I have a textbox to key in 4 numbers, once the button clicked, it will automatically shows 24 combination of the number such as 1234 1243 1324  1342 1423 1432 2134 2143 etc

Very appreciate!!!

Comment: You might want to edit your title. The proper term for what you want is "permutations" (where the order matters) rather than "combinations" (where the order doesn't matter).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just so that you know we're not a code writing service. You should attempt this yourself and when you get stuck come here and ask your question - we can then help you get your code right..

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this:

```
Dim texts = {"1", "2", "3", "4"}
Dim permutate As Func(Of IEnumerable(Of String), IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of String))) = Nothing
permutate = Function(xs) If(Not xs.Skip(1).Any(), {xs}, xs.SelectMany(Function(x, n) permutate(xs.Take(n).Concat(xs.Skip(n + 1))).[Select](Function(z) {x}.Concat(z))))
Dim result = String.Join(", ", permutate(texts).Select(Function (xs) String.Join("", xs)))
```

I get this `result`:

> 1234, 1243, 1324, 1342, 1423, 1432, 2134, 2143, 2314, 2341, 2413,
>   2431, 3124, 3142, 3214, 3241, 3412, 3421, 4123, 4132, 4213, 4231,
>   4312, 4321